# How to create a Fragment loading information from SQLDatabase?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating an activity that implements a fragment list and a regular fragment showing details of the list. i am having a VERY hard time trying to take the android developer tutorial on fragment cursor and use it.

I am trying to load the title's from my SQLdatabse into the fragment list. And when the item is clicked show details for it. I know i will just store the id of the item in a extra and pick it out in the details fragment to get the information.

Im just kind of confused on the whole ListFragment class.

Here is my source code where im at so far...

```
public class Main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = new getFragmentManager();
    if(fm.findFragmentById(android.R.id.content)== null){
        CursorLoaderListFragment list = new CursorLoaderListFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, list).commit();

    }

}
public static class CursorLoaderListFragment extends ListFragment{

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    String mCurFilter;

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            setEmptyText("No Task");
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);



        }
}
```

}

If someone has a better way than what im doing PLEASE let me know and provide an example.

Thanks!

Comment: have u got solution ? I have face same problem ....if yes pls share..